# Enable "language filtering for ajax operations" for logged-in users at WPML

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wpml

I enabled **`language filtering for ajax operations`** option in **WPML** and it works properly for the non-logged-in users as they said [Enabling a Language Cookie to Support AJAX Filtering](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/enabling-language-cookie-to-support-ajax-filtering). But I want to enable it for the logged-in users also.